# Set Time limit for Get-process

Tags: powershell

Long story short, we are experiencing issues with some of our servers that cause crippling effects on them and I am looking for a way to monitor them, now I have a script that will check the RDP port to make sure that it is open and I am thinking that I want to use `get-service` and then I will return if it pulled any data or not.

Here is the issue I don't know how to limit the time it will wait for a response before returning false.

`[bool](Get-process -ComputerName MYSERVER)`

Comment: If the problem is that you have a long list of servers, and each failure holds up the list, then try using Invoke-Command or a workflow to run the the request in parallel. If the problem is that you want to run the same request repeatedly on a few servers, then maybe there is a better way to monitor the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I like [Ansgars answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31710633/712649) with a time-limited job, I think a separate Runspace and async invocation fits this task better.

The major difference here being that a Runspace reuses the in-process thread pool, whereas the PSJob method launches a new process, with the overhead that that entails, such as OS/kernel resources spawning and managing a child process, serializing and deserializing data etc.

Something like this:

```
function Timeout-Statement {
    param(
        [scriptblock[]]$ScriptBlock,
        [object[]]$ArgumentList,
        [int]$Timeout
    )

    $Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
    $Runspace.Open()

    $PS = [powershell]::Create()
    $PS.Runspace = $Runspace
    $PS = $PS.AddScript($ScriptBlock)
    foreach($Arg in $ArgumentList){
        $PS = $PS.AddArgument($Arg)
    }

    $IAR = $PS.BeginInvoke()

    if($IAR.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne($Timeout)){
        $PS.EndInvoke($IAR)
    }

    return $false
}
```

Then use that to do:

```
$ScriptBlock = {
    param($ComputerName)

    Get-Process @PSBoundParameters
}

$Timeout = 2500 # 2 and a half seconds (2500 milliseconds)

Timeout-Statement $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList "mycomputer.fqdn" -Timeout $Timeout
```

Comment: I think this will fit in with the rest of my script the best although I agree and I like your idea too @Ansgar Wiechers I needed something like that for another script so it is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could run your check as a background job:

```
$sb = { Get-Process -ComputerName $args[0] }

$end = (Get-Date).AddSeconds(5)
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList 'MYSERVER'
do {
  Start-Sleep 100
  $finished = (Get-Job -Id $job.Id).State -eq 'Completed'
} until ($finished -or (Get-Date) -gt $end)

if (-not $finished) {
  Stop-Job -Id $job.Id
}

Receive-Job $job.Id
Remove-Job $job.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/645165/add-timeout-parameter-to-get-wmiobject

There is a workaround provided Here : https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/645165/add-timeout-parameter-to-get-wmiobject

```
Function Get-WmiCustom([string]$computername,[string]$namespace,[string]$class,[int]$timeout=15)
{
    $ConnectionOptions = new-object System.Management.ConnectionOptions
    $EnumerationOptions = new-object System.Management.EnumerationOptions

    $timeoutseconds = new-timespan -seconds $timeout
    $EnumerationOptions.set_timeout($timeoutseconds)

    $assembledpath = "\\" + $computername + "\" + $namespace
    #write-host $assembledpath -foregroundcolor yellow

    $Scope = new-object System.Management.ManagementScope $assembledpath, $ConnectionOptions
    $Scope.Connect()

    $querystring = "SELECT * FROM " + $class
    #write-host $querystring

    $query = new-object System.Management.ObjectQuery $querystring
    $searcher = new-object System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher
    $searcher.set_options($EnumerationOptions)
    $searcher.Query = $querystring
    $searcher.Scope = $Scope

    trap { $_ } $result = $searcher.get()

    return $result
}
```

You can call the function like this:

`get-wmicustom -class Win32_Process -namespace "root\cimv2" -computername MYSERVER –timeout 1`